# Get file extension of current document vscode

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension that takes in the current file type and generates a HelloWorld starter code for it. However I can not find out how to get the current file type in the vscode docs and none of the code found can work. Help will be appreciated. The current code takes in the filename and then the fileType before generating the relevant code.

```
        const documentFileType = null;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;

        if documentFileType === 'ts' {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!");');
            });
        }
```

The full code if anyone wants to see it...

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import "typescript";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log("code-boilerplate is active!");
    
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerPlate', () => {
    
        const documentFileType = null;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;

        if documentFileType === 'ts' {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!");');
            });
        }
        else if documentFileType == "py" {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'print("Hello World!")');
            });
        }
        else if documentFileType === "js" {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), 'console.log("Hello World!")');
            })
        }
        
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Generating code boilerplate...");
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {
    console.log("code-boilerplate is deactivated!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the language of the current document using
`vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId`

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument

Comment: Thank you so much I am not sure how I missed this

Comment: What will it output - e.g typescript is .ts or ts

Comment: I think that it will output "typescript" (generally the name in parentheses when you open "Change Language Mode"). Make a test extension where you log the value or show it in a message.

Comment: Thank you I checked the docs and you are correct - they use language identifiers